# How to count number of elements of each sublist in a list and return a new list

Tags: python, list, count

This is the list that I have:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 0, 6, 4], [4, 2, 3, 6, 8]]
```

I would like to count the number of elements of each sublist in the list and return a new list to have the desired output of

```
a = [3, 4, 5]
```

I know how to get the total number of elements in the list with lists but not sure how to get the number of elements in each sublist...

Comment: `a = [len(i) for i in a]` or `a = list(map(len, a))`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code: `a = [len(ele) for ele in a]`